# set anchor tag in a provided string

Tags: javascript, jquery, anchor

I want to set a anchor tag in a provided string. It search in javascript after http:// and make it to an anchor tag.

```
function createLink(text, node){//text is the provided string
    var start = text.indexOf('http://');
    var end = text.indexOf(' ', start) + 1 || text.length - 1; //provides me with the wrong index
    var link = text.substring(start, end);
    var newLink = document.createElement('a');
    newLink.href = link;
    newLink.className = 'link';
    newLink.target = '_blank';
    newLink.innerHTML = link.substr(0, 20);
    if(link.length >= 20){
        $(newLink).append('...');
    }
    var head = text.substring(0, start);
    var tail = text.substring(end);
    node.innerHTML = '';
    $(node).append(head).append(newLink).append(tail);
}
```

Comment: how are you calling this function and what is the desired end result?

Comment: I call it with the paremeters text and the node I want to append the result in. And the desired end result is that the prvodided string has a clickabla anchor. But there are some wrong with the variables start and end

Comment: yes I know I alredy have an if statement before I call the function ot ensure that the string does not contain `http://`

Comment: Something is still wrong `.indexOf(' ', start)` is -1 sometimes

Comment: I tried http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_string.asp as link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you were off by 1:

```
function createLink(text, node){ //text is the provided string
    var start = text.indexOf('http://');
    var end = (text.indexOf(' ', start) + 1 || text.length - 1) - 1;
    var link = text.substring(start, end);

    var $a = $("<a>", {
        href: link,
        "class": "link",
        target: "_blank",
        html: link.substr(0, 20) + (link.length >= 20 ? "..." : ""),
    });

    var head = text.substring(0, start);
    var tail = text.substring(end);

    $(node).append(head).append($a).append(tail);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hunter/vNrrR/

Comment: Something is still wrong .indexOf(' ', start) is -1 sometimes